# Program passing over if statement and needing pointer to object type

Tags: c, arrays, function

I keepi having a part of my code skipped over, it is when the user selects zerio and i go to if select 0 then do this, but it just skips over it entirely

```
if (select = 0)
{
    for ( i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
  printf("%d", array[i]);
    //// whenever I enter zero it skips over this if entirely
}
```

also, when I try and call a function and print it, i keep getting that i must have a pointer to object type

```
    if (select = 1)
{


    square(array, 20);

    for( j = 0; j < 20; ++j);
    printf("%d", a[j]);
    //the j reads that I need a pointer-to-object type
}
```

Here is my code in its entirety. It is an old assignment that I am playing around with trying to relearn things

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<conio.h>

    void initialize(int a[], int size)
    {

int i;


    }

    void square(int a[], int size)
    {
int j;

for( j = 0; j < size; ++j)
    a[j] = a[j] * a[j];



    }





    int main (void)
    {


   int array[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,19};          
    int i,j,k,l,m, select, a, size;


void initialize ( int a[], int size);
    void square ( int a[], int size);


printf("Please select an option from the form \n\n 0 - initialize \n\n 1 - square \n\n 2 ");
scanf("%d", &select);





if (select = 0)
{
    for ( i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
  printf("%d", array[i]);
    //// whenever I enter zero it skips over this if entirely
}
if (select = 1)
{


    square(array, 20);

    for( j = 0; j < 20; ++j);
    printf("%d", a[j]);
    //the j reads that I need a pointer-to-object type
}



    }
```

Comment: In an `if`, you use `==` and not `=` to indicate equality.

Comment: I can't even correctly indent your code to help you. Please remove the whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really common mistake:

```
if (select = 0)
```

should be

```
if (select == 0)
```

Try that. It is usually a good practice to do defensive programming

```
if (0 == select)
```

because

```
if (0 = select)
```

wont work, the compiler will yell

Comment: Please don't do `if (0 == select)`.

Comment: and why not? It is a really basic way of avoiding this mistake

Comment: Probably because by the time someone's learnt enough to use that ordering, they've also learnt not to use '=' where they meant '==', so it ends up being useless for almost all occasions!

Comment: And the other way to avoid this mistake is to pay attention to the compiler warnings.

Comment: I still do it all the time, and I have been programming for 7 years. Sometimes you get distracted or dont type it slow enough. It is just a good practice

Comment: I feel silly, thank you.

Comment: No problem at all. The compiler usually warns you about that

Comment: Also, what about the pointer objective type error I keep getting, I still dont understand that

Comment: @user3575495: I added the solution to your second error to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`=` is the assignment operator. Use `==` for comparing values.

On the second error you ask about, `a` is declared as an integer in your `main()` function:

```
    int i,j,k,l,m, select, a, size;
```

You probably meant to use `array` instead of `a` in that printf statement.

Answer (score 0):

Operator `=` is for assignment.
Operator `==` is for comparison.